# Does the G-Spot exist?

Tags: medical-science

There's a lot of talk in magazines about a woman's G-Spot.

But does it exist? Or is it a trick to keep men searching?

Comment: I am not sure skepticism is the best site for this question. Or maybe yes... but I think it's more of a medical question, rather than skeptical inquire about a topic

Comment: +1 I think there is enough myth and woo floating around in popular culture about the G spot that this qualifies for the skeptics page.  It's also not so specific that it needs to go to a medical board, in my opinion.

Comment: fair enough. +1 then

Comment: If you're lookin[g](http://images2.memegenerator.net/ImageMacro/6192495/OMG-You-Found-It.jpg?imageSize=Medium&generatorName=Lame-pun-coon) hard enough, you will find it.

Comment: Are we not pointing out [obligatory XKCD references](http://xkcd.com/685/) on this site, or what?

Comment: @Synesso:  G[ee], I found it, but wholly-404 it's Not Found!  ;+1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From personal experience, it does...

However, to be statistically more relevant, it appears that subjective body characteristics may define its sensitivity or not. Apparently, this is also the main reason why it is still an argument of research. According to [the Pedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-Spot)

> Researchers at the University of
>   L'Aquila have found, using
>   ultrasonography, that women who
>   experience vaginal orgasm are
>   statistically more likely to have
>   thicker tissue in the anterior vaginal
>   wall. The researchers believe
>   these findings make it possible for
>   women to have a rapid test to confirm
>   whether or not they have a G-Spot.[28]
>   A French study in late 2009 examined a
>   small number of women with ultrasound
>   as they had intercourse, by examining
>   changes in the vagina they found
>   physiological evidence of the G-Spot.
>   The findings are under review by the
>   Journal of Sexual Medicine.

Although it's hard to obtain conclusive information from this, [another study](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01541824) was statistically more relevant

> An anonymous questionnaire was
>   distributed to 2350 professional women
>   in the United States and Canada with a
>   subsequent 55% return rate. Of these
>   respondents, 40% reported having a
>   fluid release (ejaculation) at the
>   moment of orgasm. Further, 82% of the
>   women who reported the sensitive area
>   (Gräfenberg Spot) also reported
>   ejaculation with their orgasms. A
>   number of variables were associated
>   with this perceived existence of
>   female ejaculation.

So, the evidence points at a feature that is really person dependent, and it may certainly exists but not with the same level of sensitivity, making a clear identification difficult. In addition, being a sensitive area, and not a clearly visible feature, makes a clear identification even more complex.

Comment: You need to cite this.  Or at least link to a video.

Comment: @Stefano Borini I disagree.

Comment: @Billare : on regard to ?

Comment: @Stefano Borini I meant I disagree that you need to cite anything, sorry if that wasn't clear.  I wasn't criticizing your answer.

Comment: I can only speak for personal experience. Yes, yes it does exist. It's not always the easiest to have stimulated, but when it's hit right, well.. yeah. Happy times.

Comment: "this is also the main reason why it is still an argument of research." - I would have theorized that it's still an object of research because **what researcher in their right mind object to getting paid to research this topic?**

Comment: @DVK (+1):  If I'm reading the right undertones into your _bold_ statement (that is, the bolded part, heheh), I can think of a researcher in their right mind who may not find this particularly interesting -- a homosexual male researcher.  ;-P

Comment: @Randolf - (1) Homosexual male researchers woudln't object to getting paid for doing fun research (even if they don't get the side benefits)?  And (2) According to Kinsey's scale, there are VERY few 100% pure homosexual (vs. somewhat bisexual) people.

Answer (score 0):

Most studies (such as the ones summarized in the Wikipedia article about "Orgasm") point towards the idea that the g-spot is actually the inner part of the clitoris and nothing more. Moreover, anatomical dissections have shown that the clitoris is much bigger than what was thought at first, and its nerves extend across the vaginal wall. This could be the reason why some women have sensitivity in the area and others not, and why most women are unable to reach orgasm without direct clitoral stimulation (around 80% or so). Think about this, if it was really a different organ, why would it be absent in so many women, and why would it be so elusive? It makes more sense that the inner part of the clitoris is more developed in some women, just as some men have larger penises.
So well, in my opinion: Is there a sensitive area in that zone? In some cases, yes. But is this a g-spot separated from the clitoris? No.
In my experience at least, both zones are closely connected.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Rather than saying "most studies", please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to them, and to the anatomical dissections. Showing the clitoris is larger than thought is different to showing it to be the source of the g-spot.